# How can i make a certain template visible only to confirmed users in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls, django-allauth

I'm creating a site and I successfully added an email confirmation system using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth). Now I would like to have some parts of my site available only to users who confirmed their email.

Suppose that part looks something like this:

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% block content %}


<body>



<div>
    <p> Here are are a bunch of features etc... </p>
</div>          



</body>

{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, I know how to do that in theory, but not practically. I figured that I need to add a statement that checks if the email is confirmed. What I'm not understanding is where should I add this statement and what that should look like. Should it be on the template? Or should I create a view for this? Any advice is appreciated? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its best to put the login in your **[`CustomUser Model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)**:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    @property
    def has_verified_email(self):
        return self.emailaddress_set.filter(verified=True,primary=True).exists()
```

Then use in template:

```
 {% if user.has_verified_email %}
    // some lines 
 {% endif %}
```

If you haven't overridden your User model, then you can put it in a separate model which has a OneToOne relation to your User model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)

        @property
        def has_verified_email(self):
            return self.user.emailaddress_set.filter(verified=True,primary=True).exists()
```

Then use it in template:

```
 {% if user.profile.has_verified_email %}
    // some lines 
 {% endif %}
```

Second best option would be to use in View, but you will need to put the same logic in every view. If you are using a Class Based View, you can make a Mixin and use it in them:

```
class SomeMixin(object):
     def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         context = super(SomeMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
         context['has_verified_email'] = self.request.user.emailaddress_set.filter(verified=True,primary=True).exists()
         return context

class ActualView(SomeMixin, TemplateView):
     # subclassing from the mixin in

// template code
 {% if has_verified_email %}
    // some lines 
 {% endif %}
```